# android option menu doesn't appear when menu button is pressed

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I wanted to add an option menu to my android app.I created my_menu.xml file as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/play" android:title="Play" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/comments" android:title="Comments" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>
</menu>
```

Then I've override onCreateOptionsMenu() method in my java file as follows.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
   return true;
  }
```

When I run the app and click menu button it doesn't appear anything.
 Anyone can give me an idea to solve this.

Comment: which api level is you used ? super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) before getMenuInflater();

Comment: A LolCat output would be very helpful.

Comment: @Chirag Raval: I ckecked with your code snippet.But same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this code snippet??

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
```

I think adding this might help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the first line:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

This one:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/play" android:title="Play" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/comments" android:title="Comments" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>
</menu>
```

In combination with:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

works fine on my device.

Comment: :On which API level you tested this?

Comment: 15 - This is from my manifest
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`

Comment: If you are using a targetSdkVersion of 10 and lower, you have to use the compatibility pack. Download the samples via SDK manager and have a look here `samples\android-*\ActionBarCompat` where * is the api level. try downloading 15 or 16